# Strip words encased with '' from text inside variable and explode them into separate variables

Tags: php

Please take a look at the content of this variable:

```
$profile_rule = 'profile LIKE (\'fitness\') AND profile LIKE (\'pets\')';
```

Is there a way to strip all the text inside and just get the words fitness and pets into two separate variables?

```
$var1 = 'fitness';
$var2 = 'pets';
```

I'm not sure this could be done, but if there's a way it will save me allot of work.

Thank you!

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: Preg_match_all should be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$profile_rule = 'profile LIKE (\'fitness\') AND profile LIKE (\'pets\')';

preg_match_all('/\'(.*?)\'/',$profile_rule,$match);

print_r($match[1]);

// Outputs: Array ( [0] => fitness [1] => pets )
```